# Laravel 5 POST data to DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to insert data to db using POST request

table food_directory

id (auto incremenat)
name
fructose
polylos
fructan

```
  public function postDirec()
    {
        if (\Request::ajax()) {
            $FodMaps = \Request::get('name');
            \DB::table('food_directory')->insert([
                'food_directory' => $FodMaps,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Route

```
Route::post('postDirec', 'FodMapController@postDirec');
```

this will return Tokenmismatch issue.. please advice

Comment: What is the table structure? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CSRF-token in your form, by adding this line somewhere between your form's opening and closing tag:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: this is not for laraval form.. i want this post data from angular framework . is there any other way    to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `App\Http\Kernel.php`

And comment out this line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

It should be Line 20 in that file if you haven't made any other changes.

Comment: i want to get some data from a mobile app using POST and save it on my laravel 5 application database. 

mycontroller

     public function postBookingDetails(Request $request)
        {
    
    
            $FodMaps = $request->only('name','fructose');
    
    
            return $FodMaps;
        }

Route::post('booking', 'FodMapController@postBookingDetails');

am i in write approach ? please advice

Comment: Yep, this is the right approach. You're going good.
Oh! and If this solved your answer, Kindly Accept the answer, So that it will be helpful to others as well :)

Comment: Really? Commenting out csrf checks? that's a bad suggestion.

Comment: @michael Please suggest a better way, It would be helpful for me as well. Commenting it out is the only way I know of if I don't really wanna use the token.

Comment: lowerends allready posted the right solution. OP simply has to include the _token to his post data and evertything is working fine

Comment: That I Know, But the person asking the question wanted another solution. So, this is the only other solution that I know of.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog please see my answer to know how to avoid commenting out whole csrf protection. Your approach is bad because it would disable csrf protection for all requests. There is a way to limit it to specific routes though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable csrf protection on certain routes you can to this approach.

in the `app/Http/Middlewares/VerifyCsrfToken.php` modify `handle` method to

```
    //disable CSRF check on following routes
    $skip = [
        '/your-uri/you-want-to-disable-protection-for',
        route('or_some_route')
    ];

    foreach ($skip as $route) {
        if ($request->is($route)) {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }
    }

    return parent::handle($request, $next);
```

Put uri you want to disable into the `skip` array. It will then call the parent's class `addCookieToResponse` method that will set CSRF token to the cookie and request would be treated as protected.